# Multiple output and numba signatures

Tags: python, numba

Maybe it is trivial, but I was wondering how to write signatures in the `jit` decorator when there are several outputs.

For instance :

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(['???(int32, int32, float(:,:), float(:,:))'], nopython=True)
def foo(nx, ny, a, b):
    for i in range(nx):
        for i in range(ny):
            do stuff with a & b
    return a, b
```

What about the performances ? Is it better to write two different functions ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can either use explicit declarations or string declaration :

#### Tuple with homogeneous types :

```
@nb.jit(nb.types.UniTuple(nb.float64[:],2)(nb.float64[:]),nopython=True)
def f(a) :
    return a,a

@nb.jit('UniTuple(float64[:], 2)(float64[:])',nopython=True)
def f(a) :
    return a,a
```

#### Tuple with heterogeneous types :

```
@nb.jit(nb.types.Tuple((nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:,:]))(nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:,:]),nopython=True)
def f(a, b) :
    return a, b

@nb.jit('Tuple((float64[:], float64[:,:]))(float64[:], float64[:,:])',nopython=True)
def f(a, b) :
    return a, b
```

Source : my own experiments, and the source code of Numba : https://github.com/numba/numba

Of course, the solution proposed by DavidW is an excellent workaround when you do not know the exact type :

```
@nb.jit(nb.typeof((1.0,1.0))(nb.double),nopython=True)
def f(a):
  return a,a
```

Comment: Note the **double** parentheses when using `Tuple` in the second snippet!

Answer (score 13):

According to [this newsgroup post](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/numba-users/D3-LneSnp5k) you can specify using `numba.typeof(<an example of your tuple>)`

For example

```
import numba as nb

# I've put "nopython=True" just to demonstrate it still works
# whether you need it is your choice
@nb.jit(nb.typeof((1.0,1.0))(nb.double),nopython=True)
def f(a):
  return a,a

print f(5.0) # returns 5.0,5.0
```

You could also build them from the components given in `numba.types`, but that's probably more work than using `typeof`

The fact it can do this in nopython mode suggests performance should be OK (tuple unpacking is explicitly listed as a supported feature http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html). However, I haven't actually tested the performance.