# Why is my Numba JIT function recognized as an array?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, jit, method-signature

So I am trying to speed up a code, and while it works for most functions, a few do not work. I specify the function's signature, and it doesn't work. If I write only nb.njit, it works, but there is no speed up at all, there is even a slight slow down. When specifying the signature as in the code I posted below, I get the following error:

> TypeError: The decorated object is not a function (got type <class 'numba.core.types.npytypes.Array'>).

```
nb.njit(nb.int32[:],nb.int32[:],nb.int32[:],nb.int32[:,;](nb.int8,nb.int32[:,:],nb.int32[:,:],nb.int32[:,:],nb.int64,nb.float64[:,:])
def IdentifyVertsAndCells(i,cell_verts,vert_cells,vert_neighs,T1_edge,l):
    #Find vertices undergoing T1
    if T1_edge == len(l) - 1:
        T1_verts = cell_verts[i,[T1_edge,0]]
    else:
        T1_verts = cell_verts[i,[T1_edge,T1_edge+1]]
    
    #Identify the four cells are affected by transition
    dummy = np.concatenate((vert_cells[T1_verts[0]],vert_cells[T1_verts[1]]))
    T1cells = np.unique(dummy)

    #Identify cells that are neighbours prior to transition (that won't be afterwards)
    old_neigh = np.intersect1d(vert_cells[T1_verts[0]],vert_cells[T1_verts[1]])
    
    #Identify cells that will be neighbours after transition
    notneigh1 = T1cells[T1cells != old_neigh[0]]
    notneigh2 = T1cells[T1cells != old_neigh[1]]
    new_neigh = np.intersect1d(notneigh1,notneigh2)
    old_vert_neighs = vert_neighs[T1_verts,:]
    return T1_verts, old_neigh, new_neigh, old_vert_neighs
```

I checked the sizes and data types of my input arrays and number and am sure I did not make a mistake there. I want to add that for the number of type int8, I had to change an int to an int8 using j = np.asarray([i],dtype='int8')[0] because I didn't find a type for int, but I did for int8. The input number i in my code corresponds to that j and is indeed of type int8. When I only use inspect.isfunction on my function, it recognizes it as a function.

Here is the code calling the above function:

```
def UpdateTopology(points,verts,vert_neighs,vert_cells,cell_verts,l,x_max,y_max,T1_thresh,N):
    for i in range(N):
        #Determine how many vertices are in cell i
        vert_inds = cell_verts[i,:] < 2*N
        j = np.array([i]).astype('int8')[0]
        #If cell i only has three sides don't perform a T1 on it (you can't have a cell with 2 sides) 
        if(len(vert_inds) == 3):
            continue 
        
        #Find UP TO DATE vertex coords of cell i (can't use cell_vert_coords as
        #vertices will have changed due to previous T1 transitions)
        vert_inds = cell_verts[i,:] < 2*N
        cell_i = verts[cell_verts[i,vert_inds],:]
        
        #Shift vertex coords to account for periodicity
        rel_dists = cell_i - points[i,:]
        cell_i = ShiftCoords(cell_i,rel_dists,x_max,y_max,4)
        
        #Calculate the lengths, l, of each cell edge
        shifted_verts = np.roll(cell_i,-1,axis=0)
        l =  shifted_verts - cell_i
        l_mag = np.linalg.norm(l,axis=1)
        #Determine if any edges are below threshold length
        to_change = np.nonzero(l_mag < T1_thresh)
        #print('l = ',l)
        #print('T1_thresh = ', T1_thresh)
        if len(to_change[0]) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            T1_edge = to_change[0][0]
            #Identify vertices and cells affected, also return vert_neighs of old neighbours (to be used when updating vert_neighs later on)
            T1_verts, old_neigh, new_neigh, old_vert_neighs = T1f.IdentifyVertsAndCells(i,cell_verts,vert_cells,vert_neighs,T1_edge,l)
            #Update vertex coordinates
            verts = T1f.UpdateVertCoords(j,verts,points,cell_i,old_neigh,T1_verts,T1_thresh,l,T1_edge,x_max,y_max)    
            #Update vert_cells
            vert_cells = T1f.UpdateVertCells(verts,points,vert_cells,T1_verts,old_neigh,new_neigh)
            #Update cell_verts 
            cell_verts = T1f.UpdateCellVerts(verts,points,cell_verts,T1_verts,old_neigh,new_neigh,N)
            #Update vert_neighs
            vert_neighs = T1f.UpdateVertNeighs(vert_neighs,points,cell_verts,T1_verts,old_neigh,new_neigh,old_vert_neighs,N)

    return verts, vert_neighs, vert_cells, cell_verts
```

Comment: This won't get any faster because this is not python code, these are numpy functions, which are c++, not python, and you can only speed up python code, not c++

Comment: and you should look for the correct syntax of njit, as your syntax is wrong.

Comment: I still obtained some speed up on other functions using numpy so I expected some time gain on this one too. Also, sorry but what do you mean when you say that my syntaxt is wrong? I knwo that people usually write @njit but tha didn't work for me (or maybe the siganture was wrong at the time) but anyway using that syntax it does work for other functions. Thanks for yoour fast answer to my question. Out of curiosity (since that's my first time asking something on stackoverlfow), are answers usually that fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is related to the wrongly-defined signature that you're providing to the `njit` decorator. Whenever your jitted function returns several values, you have to define the return type as either an homogeneous tuple (if all the return types are the same) or heterogeneous tuple (if the return types are different) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35654032/4664776) answer).

Regarding the speedup, you won't get any with this code sample: rather you'll get a slowdown. The main reasons I can recognize are the following two:

1. You are only resorting on `numpy`'s standard functions, that are already highly optimized. As a rule of thumb, `numba` works well in speeding up loops. If you're code is already vectorized, you probably won't get any speed improvement by `njit`ting your function.
2. You're using a lot of fancy indexing, e.g. `cell_verts[i,[T1_edge,T1_edge+1]]`, which produce array copies that require memory allocation, a task to which `numba` is not really good at (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61375396/4664776) answer).

Comment: Oh thanks, that's a bummer that I cannot optimize it. Thanks for your answer, I had the same poblem with a bunch of other functions, hopefully some of them will be sped up!

Comment: @BilalBOTTÉ I think the function can be optimized, but not using numba. If you provide more details maybe I can help you. For example, can you provide an example code in which you would use the function `IdentifyVertsAndCells`?

Comment: It's too long to be added here, I edited my question with the function calling 'IdentifyVertsAndCells'. I sped up this function with numba, using the syntax you recommended me. To explain a bit, I am modelling a biological tissue with a Voronoi tessalation. T1 transitionare vents where the cells change neighbours by a vertex being replaced by another one. All the T1 transition functions are similar to 'IdentifyVertsAndCells' in that they do not contain any loop and mostly vectorized numpy. After your advice I decided to not use numba for any of them. Thank you for all this help!